# How to import local Typescript-Package with own node_modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, node-modules

I am developing an independent package A written in Typescript, which depends on some node packages, especially the package C. Therefore it has its own package.json and node_modules. The package fully builds.

I am now fronting the problem to import the package A into another package B, which also has a few dependencies, especially the package C.

```
- A (depends on C)
  - node_modules
    - C
     ...
  - package.json
  ...
- B (depends on C)
  - node_modules
    - C
     ...
  - package.json
  ...
- C (third-party package, eg. mathjs)
```

I have done this by adding a path to tsconfig.json, which points to the source of package A. The problem is that whenever I import A into B, the node_modules are used from both, A and B, mixed. So C is imported two times, and the types of C in these two imports of C are considered as two different types each.

What is the best practice for including a local TS-package without doubling common third-party-dependencies?

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` and `tscongfig.json` for the example that isn't working?

Comment: It is the job of npm, not yours.